# What is wrong with this if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

For some reason my program won't go onto the 'else' part even if the condition is not met.

```
if score_str >= 3:
    print("Pass")

    self.prefect = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = "You have passed, well done! You can now become a prefect.")
    self.prefect.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    self.name = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = student_name)
    self.name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    self.surname = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = student_surname)
    self.surname.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    self.tutor = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = student_tutor_group)
    self.tutor.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
else:
    print("Fail")

    self.fail = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = "Unfortunately you have not scored highly enough to be considered for a prefect position.")
    self.fail.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: You've got to give us more to work with here.  Demo it for us.  And strip it down to the simplest example (remove as many of the other lines as possible).  Usually that'll solve your problem before you need to post here.

Comment: You would've solved this yourself with some basic debugging. Step one: `4 >= 3` --> `True` (to make sure that you're not going insane). Step two: `type(score_str)`. Done :p. All I'm saying is, don't rush it.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ: That presumes you know enough about Python types; in some other languages strings containing digits are automatically coerced and the comparison would be made numerically. Python 2 has made the mistake to allow comparisons between strings and numbers just so you can sort a list containing mixed types. That leads to confusion like this. At least Python 3 now raises an exception when you make this mistake.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree, it's a mistake :p But I wouldn't say this requires any specific knowledge about Python types. Type checking is a basic thing to check in these scenarios in most languages. I did assume he/she knew about types though. You're absolutely right about my type check being worthless though, what's needed is googling of the phrase "compare string to int python" :p But it'd get you there nonetheless.

Answer (score 8):

From the name I infer that `score_str` is a string; if so, then your comparison always fails because in Python 2, numbers always sort before strings:

```
>>> '1' > 1
True
```

Make your score an integer when comparing so that you are at least making a numeric comparison:

```
if int(score_str) >= 3:
```

In Python 3, comparing strings and integers (or any two types that don't explicitly define a comparison) will result in an exception:

```
>>> '1' > 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

which would have helped you avoid this problem.